# How to grep and filter out at the same time?

Tags: shell, grep

how can I grep a line starting with number 2 excluding number 26 after the tab

file1.txt:

```
2    0   'C001000'
2    26 'C001000' So we come to step 3
2    0   'C001000'
2    26 'C001000' So we come to step 3


expected output 

    2    0   'C001000'
    2    0   'C001000'
```

my approach
cat file1.txt | grep '^2'     // which grabs all line staring with 2

```
cat file1.txt | grap '^2' $(printf '\t') '26'
```

Comment: Add what you've tried and exact output required for the given sample. I'm guessing you want only 2nd and 4th line in output?

Comment: I want to have line starting with 2 followed by tab and then excluding  number starting with 26.  Basically in above table I want to remove second and fourth  line which has 26 number after tab

Comment: I have updated with my effort

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the requirement from the OP's comment: *line starting with 2 followed by tab and then excluding number starting with 26* - and grep:

```
$ grep $'^2[\t]\(2[^6]\|[^2]\)' file
```

Output using sample data:

```
2       0       'C001000'
2       0       'C001000'
```

Explained some:

- `grep $'\t'` This syntax is used to grep for tab
- `^2[\t]` *line starting with 2 followed by tab*
- `\(2[^6]\|[^2]\)` *and then* [my definition<sup>*</sup> of] *excluding number starting with 26*
- `\(2[^6]\|[^2]\)` is basically *starts with a 2 followed by anything but a 6 or starts with anything but a 2*

Comment: can you please explain me your definition of excluding 26 . am quite new and didnt get that part

Comment: Added an explaining bullet.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I can understand, this should work:

```sh
awk -F'\t' '$1==2 && $2!=26' ip.txt
```

This will process fields based on tab character. If first field is `2` and second field is *not* `26`, the line will be printed.

If you need to print lines that start with `2` like `2a` as well, use:

```sh
awk -F'\t' '$1 ~ /^2/ && $2!=26' ip.txt
```

The above solutions will work only if the character after second field is tab as well. If that is not the case, then this might work, but need a better description of the input.

```sh
awk -F'\t' '$1==2 && $2 !~ /^26([[:space:]]|$)/' ip.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

With GNU `grep`:

```sh
grep -P '^2(?!\t26\b)' file
```

where

- `-P` - enables the PCRE regex engine
- `^2(?!\t26\b)` - matches

  - `^` - start of string (jhere, line)
  - `2` - a `2`
  - `(?!\t26\b)` - not followed with a tab and `26` as a whole word (`\b` is a word boundary). You might use `(?!\t26(?:\t|$))` or `(?!\t26(?![^\t]))` to make sure `26` is matched only in between tab chars/end of the string.

See an [online demo](https://ideone.com/eT758b):

```sh
s="2    0   'C001000'
2   26  'C001000'   So we come to step 3
2   0   'C001000'
2   26  'C001000'   So we come to step 3"
grep -P '^2(?!\t26\b)' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
2   0   'C001000'
2   0   'C001000'
```